# My JavaScript clock widget crashes Firefox

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, crash, out-of-memory

I am a JavaScript noob and realise that I need assistance.

All I want is to show a simple real-time clock with the time and AM/PM in separate SPANs.

The issue is that if I keep the tab open for 20-40 minutes (varies depending on how many other tabs I have open), it crashes the tab with an out of memory error. I have only tested this on Firefox (72.0.2) for now.

Why is my code so awfully memory intensive? It usually starts at around 2.4MB and then gradually increases and exceeds 42MB, then drops again, increases again and repeats the cycle several times until the tab crashes.

I've read aboout Garbage Collection but have no idea about how it works or if it's related to this problem.

Note that I've tried swapping setInterval with setTimeout but it's the same result.

This is my JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
  clock();

  function clock() {
    var now = new Date();
    var TwentyFourHour = now.getHours();
    var hour = now.getHours();
    var min = now.getMinutes();
    var sec = now.getSeconds();
    var mid = 'PM';

    if (min < 10) {
      min = "0" + min;
    }
    if (hour > 12) {
      hour = hour - 12;
    }
    if (hour == 0) {
      hour = 12;
    }
    if (TwentyFourHour < 12) {
      mid = 'AM';
    }

    document.getElementById('time-core').innerHTML = hour + ':' + min;
    setInterval(clock, 1000);
    document.getElementById('time-suffix').innerHTML = mid;
    setInterval(clock, 1000);
  }
}
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<span class="show-time" id="time-core"></span><span class="show-time-suffix" id="time-suffix"></span>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Every call of `clock()` adds two new intervals that each will call `clock()`. So after the first round we then have two scheduled `clock()` calls, then 4, then 8, then ...

Comment: You're setting two new intervals every time an interval calls the function. Pull the interval definitions out of `clock` function.

Comment: Replace the `clock();` call at the top with `setInterval(clock, 1000);` and remove the `setInterval` calls from your function. (setInterval will already call your function again and again, unlike setTimeout which you do need to run again and again)

Comment: Or remove one of the `setInterval`s and replace the other with `setTimeout`

Comment: Thanks, all you lifesavers. Trying @chris-g recommendation and it's completely stable now.
Will monitor for crashes.
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402037/andreas) said in his comment:

> Every call of clock() adds two new intervals that each will call clock(). So after the first round we then have two scheduled clock() calls, then 4, then 8, then ...

One way to solve that would be to remove the `setInterval` from inside the `clock` function, like the example below.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  clock(); // Run it first so we don't have to wait 1 second
  setInterval(clock, 1000); // Updates the clock every second

  function clock() {
    var now = new Date();
    var TwentyFourHour = now.getHours();
    var hour = now.getHours();
    var min = now.getMinutes();
    var sec = now.getSeconds();
    var mid = 'PM';

    if (min < 10) {
      min = "0" + min;
    }
    if (hour > 12) {
      hour = hour - 12;
    }
    if (hour == 0) {
      hour = 12;
    }
    if (TwentyFourHour < 12) {
      mid = 'AM';
    }

    document.getElementById('time-core').innerHTML = hour + ':' + min;
    document.getElementById('time-suffix').innerHTML = mid;
  }
}
```

Comment: You're a Jangel (JavaScript Angel). Thanks!